# How to use swagger in react native

Tags: react-native, swagger, swagger-codegen

I'm very new to swagger, Just exploring it without knowing much about java-script. I came from Java background.

In Android project I used to follow these steps to use Swagger.

1. define `YAML`
2. Generate `api` and `to` using swagger codegen tool
3. copy generated `.api` and `.to` to project
   - define wrapper for api
   - make generatd `to` extend base class
4. use api wrapper to request server.

Now, I need to use same `yaml` in react native too. There is no single tutorial I found anywhere on the web. Why It is so hidden I'm not getting.

I just needed an example to request a list of `pets` from `petstore`. Can anyone give a very simple straight forward step by step tutorial to achieve this. Kindly, Don't write much theory. I'm looking for some practical answers.

here is [petstore yaml](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/examples/v2.0/yaml/petstore.yaml)

here is [swagger codegen](https://editor.swagger.io/)

Comment: You don't have to "bind" to Rest API's. You can simply copy the sample response shown in the Swagger UI and use that as the starting point for your class.

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi Thank you, But i didn't understood what you said. I'm very new and I need some examples or little more elaborate answer to understand. If you mention the steps it would be great !